# How can i get rid of the multiple SMS auth?

Tags: javascript, php, bitrix

I posted my code examples below. Basically the whole idea is to make a simple authentification with a phone number and generated 6-digit code. User is posting a code in a field and it is done. But i have a slight problem. Every time i refresh a page site is asking to make an auth again. Or if i use a function to get rid of it, it starts to make a multiple SMS with codes. Frontend is JS and backend is PHP.

Here is my frontend auth code

```
$(document).on('submit', "#reg", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    var enteredPhone = $('#phone').val();
    sendFormToServer(form, function(data) {
        $('#error-message').text("");
        $('#reg').hide();
        $('#regButton').hide();
        $('#verificationForm').show();
        
        verificationCode = data.verification_code;
        
    });
});
function sendFormToServer(form, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: actionUrl,
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            handleServerError(xhr);
        }
    });
}
function lk_auth(data) {

    const obj = data;
    if (obj.sendt_to) {
        setCookie('auth', true);
        setCookie('contactID', obj.sendt_to, options = {});
        setCookie('phone', obj.phone, options = {});
        console.log('auth = ' + getCookie('auth') + ' contactID = ' + getCookie('contactID') + 'phone = ' + getCookie('phone'));

        const $menu = $('<div class="header__menu"></div>');


    $menu.append('<span style="display:none" id="documents"></span >');
        $menu.append('<span style="display:none" id="chat"></span >');
        $menu.append('<span style="display:none" id="payments"></span >');
  
        $('#reg').hide();
    $('#verificationForm').hide();
        $('#body').append($menu);
    $('#error-message').hide();
    }
    

    const $content = $('<div class="div0"></div>');
    $content.append('<div class="header__menu">Phone: ' + getCookie('phone') + '</div');
    $content.find('.header__menu').css('display', 'none');

    $('#content').empty();
    $('#content').append($content);
}
```

Now the backend of making the SMS itself

```
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
        $phone = trim(str_replace(array('-', ' '), '', $_POST['phone']));
        $contactData['msg'] = 'Телефон: ' . $phone;
        $resultContactID = CRest::call(
            'crm.duplicate.findbycomm',
            array(
                'entity_type' => "CONTACT",
                'type' => "PHONE",
                'values' => array($phone)
            )
        );

        if (empty($resultContactID['result']['CONTACT'])) {
            $contactData['msg'] .= ' No personal account is registered';
            http_response_code(403);
        } elseif (count($resultContactID['result']['CONTACT']) > 1) {
            $contactData['msg'] .= ' attention there is more than 1 contacts ' . count($resultContactID['result']['CONTACT']) . ' contacts!';
            http_response_code(500);
        } else {
            $contactData['ID'] = $resultContactID['result']['CONTACT'][0];
            $message = generateRandomCode();
            $api_token = '*****';
            $url = "https://sms.ru/sms/send?api_id=$api_token&to=$phone&msg=$message&json=1";
            $resultContactID = CRest::call(
                'crm.duplicate.findbycomm',
                array(
                    'entity_type' => "CONTACT",
                    'type' => "PHONE",
                    'values' => array($phone)
                )
            );

            $contactData['ID'] = $resultContactID['result']['CONTACT'][0];
            $response = file_get_contents($url);
            $result = json_decode($response);

            if ($result->status == "OK") {
                $_SESSION['verification_code'] = $message;
                $contactData['status'] = 'sent';
                $contactData['message'] = 'SMS sent successfully ';
                $contactData['sendt_to'] = $contactData['ID'];
                $contactData['verification_code'] = $message;
                $contactData['phone'] = $phone;
            } else {
                $contactData['status'] = 'error';
                $contactData['message'] = 'Error in sending SMS';
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($contactData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saving something to the session to determine whether the user has successfully authenticated?

Comment: [stop form resubmitting refresh](https://www.google.com/search?q=stop+form+submitting+again+on+refresh+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @geertjanknapen yes i am saving the code that was written by user and then send it to server to check for correctness

Comment: Ok. but after that, when the user inputs the code and you've verified that it's correct, you need to then save something in the Session which shows the user has successfully authenticated. Then you can check that Session value again at the start of subsequent requests (to restricted pages/resources), so that you know whether you need to ask the user to authenticate or not.

Comment: I'm kinda new to this session thing and didn't know that this is necessary

Comment: Hm. I see. If you don't even know the basics of Sessions then I wonder if you are really at the right level to be writing an authentication system. It isn't straightfoward and there are plenty of opportunities to get it badly wrong - which is something you definitely don't want if this is going to be for a real website. You're including 2FA tokens too, which is great but also adds to the complexity. If you're not experienced at this I'd strongly advise you to use some ready-made authentication code from a reliable source, instead. Then focus on learning PHP and adding other value to your app

Comment: Thanks for explaining with the words I could not seem to find @ADyson :). And for Max, ADyson has a really good point, authentication can be very complex and is very important to do right, perhaps start with 'normal' email + password authentication, get that done right, and then start looking into something more complex. Doing some work to get you up to speed with sessions is also great, but maybe don't start with something as complex as this.

Comment: Probably i shouldn't have created this kind of authentication, but it actually works, just with a couple more SMS than i need. So i think there is a problem  somewhere in a code, but I can't find one

Comment: Well I think we've already explained what the problem is, and what you need to do about it. Refer back to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77408899/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-multiple-sms-auth?noredirect=1#comment136467252_77408899)